# How to display only fields value against mailchimp list

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I am trying to get fields value against mailchimp list and i am creating a API call for that using laravel 5.5. when i hit get url in postman it display nothing and shows status 200OK.

Here is my Controller:

```
 const REQUEST_URL = 'https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';
public function getFields()
{
    $list = 'ba6de7f809';
    $ch = curl_init(self::REQUEST_URL.$list.'/members/?fields=members.email_address');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:'.'aaaaxxxxxxyyyyyyy-us17(MY API KEY)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $error = curl_error ( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

where i am doing wrong? your help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is in `$result`,  `$httpCode`, `$error` after you execute your code?